# Can I intercept SMS messages on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sms

Can I intercept SMS messages on the iPhone? I would like to intercept messages and NOT have them display on the phone and then send out an auto reply. Is this possible in 3.x? Is it something they may alow in the future?

Comment: Check out the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058001/react-on-incoming-sms-on-an-iphone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. Nor is there a method of accessing already delivered text messages. (Even if you could, without background processing I'm not sure how your app would work anyway?)

Answer (score 1):

While the OS stack might be locked down I wonder if it is possible to access the radio layer via serial and control local delivery by issuing GSM AT commands?  I don't have access to an IPhone it may very well not be possible.

Comment: anything is "possible", but not if you want to be allowed on the app store ;)

Comment: I do not want to put my application on app store. Then, how can I intercept SMS on iPhone?