# Listening for iMessage or SMS via private API's

Tags: objective-c, iphone-privateapi, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller, imessage, private-messaging

i am trying to develop an internal application for my organisation, but i need to detect incoming sms or imessage received on that device, and send some silent sms.
I am still not able to find any helpful code that i can use in order to achieve what i want.

I tried to use ChatKit.framework but i am not able to make it work( i am receiving error linking on building)

Is there any other private framework? or is someone able to make the chatkit framework work with a valid project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're not able to achieve what you want and also get the app on the App Store. You do however mention that your app is used internally and maybe it's not an issue then. I would look into `CoreTelephony`.

Here are some resources to get your started:

- http://tech.ruimaninfo.com/?p=83
- https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/index.html
- [Detect incoming SMS or iMessage without Jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625095/detect-incoming-sms-or-imessage-without-jailbreak)