# How to read OTP from SMS message in iPhone which comes with blue underline in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

OTP for transaction at ….. for INR 121.00 on your ….. Debit Card is 123456. OTP valid for 10 minutes. Do not share your OTP with anyone.

unable to read OTP which comes with blue underline . But if the OTP comes with grey underline can be read . Is there any Sollutions to read OTP which comes with blue underline ? And also is it possible to read OTP without tapping on prompt shown in keyboard? Suggestions on this would be helpfu l if possible along with the example code .

Comment: It is not possible to get the OTP without the user tapping the keyboard bar. If you are getting numbers with a blue underline it sounds like they might be being interpreted as phone numbers. Your message is a lot longer and more complicated than the typical OTP message. I would try something like "Your code is 123456 for transaction ..." put the number earlier in the message

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71153222/how-to-auto-fill-otp-textfield-on-otp-code-received-from-firebase-in-ios-swift

This answers your question.

Comment: Is there any Sollutions for the blue underline OTP SMS message which can be fixed  from IOS side?

Comment: @Paulw11 is there any Sollutions without changing the message format .? keeping the same format of message .

Comment: ios tries to work out which messages have OTP codes in them. It seems that your message doesn't look like an OTP code.

Comment: @Paulw11 But this kind of OTP format is actually working with one APP, so what may be the solution they would have followed. Any one who have faced this kind of issue please answer. Thank you in advance.