# ios - triggering a method when a sms is received

Tags: ios, objective-c, service

I'm searching for a way to trigger a method/function when an SMS is received to the phone. Is it possible? as I know background processes are not possible in iOS.

Is there anyway of doing this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Apple do not allow to access sms,call trigger function. On android you can do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do this on a standard iPhone. This maybe possible for a jailbroken device. Please refer the following thread.

[react on incoming sms on an iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058001/react-on-incoming-sms-on-an-iphone)