# Could an iOS application read/access SMS text?

Tags: ios, iphone, sms, messageui

I want to implement an iOS application which will use the SMS text as raw information. I think Apple does not allow this. Could an iOS application read/access SMS text? or do we have any other approach to do the same?

Modification: Can we read service messages which are not saved in the SMS box like balance message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone app reading sms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656723/iphone-app-reading-sms)

Comment: The app can only send SMS, can't read/receive SMS in iOS.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Correct, you cannot access these on a standard, non-jailbroken iPhone. You should file a bug with Apple, perhaps they'll improve SMS access in the future.

1. Not possible
2. Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)
3. For SMS sending through application allowed but for accessing inbox for sms/email not allowed.

It is only possible when the phone is Jailbreaked. There are many tools to jailbreak your phone.

Once Jailbreaked, an application cal open the SQLite database at

/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db
and read the message table.

It contains, the date/time at which the message was received, the sender/recipient phone number and even the clear text of the message.

Comment: With some of the un-sandboxing of iOS 8.0, is this still the case?

Comment: I've seen some apps that intercept text messages (in a read only manner) as part of their reg flow.  But haven't found anything on how to do this.

Comment: Hi Andre, which are those apps you are referring to?

Comment: On iOS 12 there is such option, see here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that it can only be done on jailbroken phones.

Put this launchd plist in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons.` It will trigger the script whenever the sms database changes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>Label</key>
 <string>com.billybob.SMSremote</string>
 <key>ProgramArguments</key>
 <array>
 <string>/usr/sbin/script</string>
 </array>
 <key>Nice</key>
 <integer>20</integer>
 <key>WatchPaths</key>
 <array>
 <string>/private/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db</string>
 </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

For the script I'd use something like the following to determine if there is a message containing the string:

```
sqlite3 /var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db "select 'String Found' from message where text like '&&XX&&' order by date desc limit 1"
```

for the whole script maybe

```
case $( sqlite3 /var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db "select 'String Found' from message where text like '&&XX&&' order by date desc limit 1" ) in 'String Found') sqlite3 /var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db "delete * from message where text like '&&XX&&'" ; commandscript;;esac
```

In order words when the string is found, delete all messages containing the string and execute the commandscript.

Of course you need a jailbroken phone and sqlite from cydia. The same process could be done on the other databases as well. I'm not sure how you would go about doing this without a shell script but I'm sure it's possible. I haven't tested the script yet so you might want to make a copy of your sms.db before trying.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8120599/4731224