# is it possible to load user's SMS messages on IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

In my apps, I want to access to user's SMS messages from the system database. Is it possible to read user's messages inside my apps?

Comment: If you are wondering why apple doesn't allow access to messages, but there are so many texting apps this is because these apps have there own servers or back end services that send messages from phone to phone in their apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Apple doesn't allow apps to access messages. Sorry.

However, if you are developing an application for jailbroken phones, all the messages are stored in an sqlite file. You can find more information about that [here](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Messages#Main_database_file).

Answer (score 0):

It not possible.

This topic may useful: [Could an iOS application read/access SMS text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19603832/could-an-ios-application-read-access-sms-text)